# Pandas 1.5.3 vs. Pandas 2.0.1. Getting different results when performing arithmetic operations on dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a script that includes getting the difference between two dates in months. Initially, I created this script with pandas 1.5.3 and things worked as I expected. However, when I switched environments and used pandas 2.0.3, things changed enough the end results. After some investigating, I traced the problem to the fact that when I perform arithmetic operations on datetime objects, I would get slightly different results in these two pandas versions. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date1 = pd.to_datetime('2022-07-25')
date2 = pd.to_datetime('2023-07-25')

diff = (date2-date1)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')

print(diff)
```

Pandas 1.5.3: 11.992
Pandas 2.0.3: 11.774

I tried reading through some of the release notes of pandas > 2.0, but didn't find anything relevant to this? Did I miss something? Can anyone explain this difference?

Comment: Might be something related to month length. 365÷11.992 = 30.437, which is approximately equal to the **average** month length, 365.2÷12 = 30.4333. 365÷11.774 = 31.0005, which is approximately equal to the **longest** month length, 31.

Comment: Whoops, a year is 365.2425 days, which ÷12 = 30.4369, which is = 30.437 with rounding. So that makes even more sense.

Comment: The same thing happens with years: `(date2 - date1) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')` -> Pandas 1.5.3: `0.9993360575508052`; Pandas 2.0.1: `1.0`

Comment: Wait, why is this even possible in the first place? I can't get the division to work with any other combinations of things: NumPy over NumPy, Python over NumPy, or Pandas over `dateutil` `relativedelta`. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: The [NumPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) say: *"There are two Timedelta units (‘Y’, years and ‘M’, months) which are treated specially, because how much time they represent changes depending on when they are used. While a timedelta day unit is equivalent to 24 hours, there is no way to convert a month unit into days, because different months have different numbers of days."*

Comment: @wjandrea Does this mean the conversion from days into months isn't possible to do accurately? I'll debug a bit more and see what I can find. For context, Numpy versions are exactly the same (1.23.5). Not sure what changed with pandas, but something alters these results just enough to give me trouble. Np.ceil solves my issue, but I'm just curious as to why.